# Resources to compare Java to Objective-C (syntax and basics)

Tags: java, objective-c, programming-languages

I have taught myself a lot of Objective-C over the past year and a half, and have even been able to publish some iOS apps on the App Store.  Concepts that were foreign to me before about object oriented programming are now second nature and I understand MVC, inheritance, polymorphism etc.  I'm now interested in learning to develop for the Android platform, which will entail learning Java.  I want to find resources that can match up Java basics with regards to syntax and structure with the same things from the Objective-C world.

[The Wikipedia entry for Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Syntax) has exactly what I'm looking for with regards to how Objective-C relates to C++.  If there is a document, blog post or book dedicated to something like this for Java in relation to Objective-C I would be all over it like a bear on honey.  It should include things like

- Class method declarations and implementations
- instance method declarations and implementations
- How to compose a method name (ie +/-(returntype)methodName:(type)argument; )
- declaring properties

Thank you for all of your suggestions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Matching up syntax" is not necessarily a useful thing. The two languages are not merely different syntaxes for the same thing. Lots of people go into a new language with that mindset, and it leads them to write bad code in their new language. For example, class methods in Objective-C are roughly equivalent to static methods in Java, but class methods can be overridden in subclasses while static methods can only be hidden by new static methods — they're more similar to namespaced functions than methods.

Better to just learn Java from a good book or tutorial — *without* your baggage from Objective-C.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with this statement.

Comment: I want to try to port some of my iOS foundation code to Java, (sans Cocoa of course) and am curious on how to create my base classes and get them set up. I use a bunch of custom objects and would like to get them initialized in a Java environment.  So that's why I'm looking for a syntax comparison, because I'm interested in porting

Comment: I will mark this as my selected answer if you can point me to a good Java resource that you're aware of that is geared towards anyone who has programmed Objective-C

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's some decent info in these slides: http://jonathanlehr.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/objective-c-and-java.pdf if you can get past the generic introductions.

Comment: Upvoted but can't look at this behind my proxy at work =( I will follow up soon!  Thank you for the link, sir